# preload images in document folder swift

Tags: image, swift, preload

**It's the situation**: I have my xcode project, a sqlite database, and images.
In the database I have the relative paths (VARCHAR) so I can access to the images salved in the document folder. If I let user download images after installation, it takes so long.

How can I preload images in document folder when the app is installed?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you save images in documents folder? can't you create imageSets in your xCode project and then use them in code?

Comment: How can I create imageSets? I have about 700 images.

Comment: I don't see the problem. If it takes too much time, why don't you create a folder in your xCode project and import all your images in that folder?

Comment: The problem is the database will be updated later, in this case I think I can't save image in xcode folder. If I have my images in document folder, with new records, I can still save relative path in database and create the image in document folder.

Comment: At first launch, you want to create SQLite database and save all images in documents folder. This is possible, but if you don't want to download these images from network, images must be in your project, otherwise what do you save locally? You should implement code to retrieve images in project and copy them in phone documents folder saving their relative paths on SQLite db

Comment: can you please show me some code of how to retrieve images in project?